# I am continually getting a 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null' response and can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, null, typeerror

I realize that I am probably looking past something glaringly obvious, but so far I can't seem to find it. I need a second pair of eyes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var t;
        t=document.getElementById('temperture');
        var v;
        v=document.getElementById('speed');
        var h;
        h=document.getElementById('hum');
        function dpOnClick(){
          if (h.value < 50){
            alert('There is no dew point below 50% humidity');}
          else{
            document.getElementById('outputBox').innerHTML='The dew point would be '+  t.value - ((100 - (h.value)/100)/2.778);}

    return false;
    }

</script>
    <title> Weather Indexes </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Weather Indexes</h2>
    <p> Enter degees in fahrenheit and select calculation.</p>
    <p> Degrees: <input type="number" id="temperture" size=12 value=''> °F </p>
    <p> Wind Speed: <input type="number" id="speed" size=12 value='' > mph </p>
    <p> Relative Humidity: <input type="number" id="hum" size=12 value='' ></p>

    <input type="button" value="Dew Point" onclick="dpOnClick();">

    <hr> <div id="outputBox"></div> </hr>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Move your <script>.....</script> at the end of body tag. you can't get the element before generated.

Comment: I love you. I can't believe I braincrapped that bad...

Comment: Ok new problem, now its telling me that it's not a number when I use my button. I think I'm just too spent to see the problem, can you see it?

Comment: its better if all your script stays at one place, in the header. Just wrap it with document.windows.onload, look at my answer, I also explained why this happens, in case you encounter this again in future

Comment: Because It's actually not a number...the value is a string which you can use `typeof t.value` to check. You should chagne to `parseInt(t.value)` instead.

Comment: It actually turned out I just had to add a rounding function and it worked out. Thank you though, if it stops working again I will throw that in.

Comment: Ok, I added in the rounder, but now i'm just getting the wrong number. I have the formula correct. Or at least as I have found it, and I am cross-checking my results with the top google hit site, and my results are different.

Answer (score 1):

Put the script at the end of body tag..

or put this lines:

```
    t=document.getElementById('temperture');
    v=document.getElementById('speed');
    h=document.getElementById('hum');
```

into **window.onload** .

This happens because your DOM is not yet created when it was being fetched by the javascript, thats why it returns null or undefined.

**Edit**

Its window.load not document.window.load, sorry for typo.

Check this fiddle to see what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/k3moqkkt/1/

Again its better if your script remain in header tag.

Answer (score 0):

- To fix Uncaught TypeError ,you can move script tag after the html element you want get or you can put these code to body `onload` event.
- To fix number format error you can check the input data type by `typeof` and use `parseInt / parseFloat` to change input value to number.

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Weather Indexes </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Weather Indexes</h2>
<p> Enter degees in fahrenheit and select calculation.</p>
<p> Degrees: <input type="number" id="temperture" size=12 value=''> °F </p>
<p> Wind Speed: <input type="number" id="speed" size=12 value=''> mph </p>
<p> Relative Humidity: <input type="number" id="hum" size=12 value=''></p>
<input type="button" value="Dew Point" onclick="dpOnClick();">
<hr>
<div id="outputBox"></div>
</hr>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var t;
    t = document.getElementById('temperture');
    var v;
    v = document.getElementById('speed');
    var h;
    h = document.getElementById('hum');
    function dpOnClick() {
        if (h.value < 50) {
            alert('There is no dew point below 50% humidity');
        }else {
            document.getElementById('outputBox').innerHTML = 
            'The dew point would be ' + 
            parseInt(t.value) - ((100 - parseInt(h.value) / 100) / 2.778);
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>

</html>`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have to read the values when the button is clicked, not at some other time. So make that part of the *dpOnClick* function:

```
function dpOnClick(){
  var t = document.getElementById('temperture');
  var v = document.getElementById('speed');
  var h = document.getElementById('hum');

  if (h.value < 50) {
    alert('There is no dew point below 50% humidity');

  } else {
    document.getElementById('outputBox').innerHTML = 'The dew point would be ' + (t.value - (100 - h.value)/100/2.778);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Also, you have to contain the entire arithmetic part in brackets as otherwise string concatenation turns the result into NaN after the first `-`.